# Creating XML-child's from a list

Tags: xml, list, python-2.7

I want to iterate over a list and create for each list-element a child entry in my XML-File. To create the XML-File I use lxml with etree. I could do:

```
heads = ["foo", "foobar", "fooboo"]

child1 = etree.SubElement(root, heads[0])
child2 = etree.SubElement(root, heads[1])
...
```

But I want to do it automatically - if there are 10 list items, there should be 10 child entries in the XML-File. I've tried something like this:

```
for i_c, i in enumerate(heads):
     a = "child_%i = etree.SubElement(root, %s)" % (i_c, i)
     exec a
```

Im pretty new to Python.. so please don't mind. :)

Greetings,
Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use:

```
import lxml.etree as etree
root = etree.Element('root')
heads = ["foo", "foobar", "fooboo"]
for head in heads:
    etree.SubElement(root, head)
```

You don't need to define `child_n` because you can access them through `root[n]`:

```
In [114]: list(root)
Out[114]: 
[<Element foo at 0x7fa434bdf680>,
 <Element foobar at 0x7fa434bdf560>,
 <Element fooboo at 0x7fa434bdfab8>]

In [115]: root[1]
Out[115]: <Element foobar at 0x7fa434bdf560>
```

---

Tip: Whenever you start naming variables with numerals (e.g. `child_1`, `child_2`), there is a very good chance you should instead be using *one* variable (e.g. `root`) which is a tuple, list or dict (or in this case, an `Element` that supports list-like indexing).

Thus, if `root` was not list-like and you wanted to collect the children
Elements in a list, you could use

```
child = list()
for head in heads:
    child.append(etree.SubElement(root, head))
```

Then, instead of `child_n` you could access the `nth` child using `child[n-1]` (since Python uses 0-based indexing).

Comment: I didn't know that I could access the child's through the main element.. Thanks a lot!